# Why is there line being drawn beneath my bootstrap forms?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a CSS sticky `footer` defined as follows:

```css
#foot {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   text-align: right;
   padding-top: 7px;
   font-size: small;
   background-color: none;
}
```

What looks like a horizontal line appears at the bottom of all `form`s. When I remove the `position: fixed` (or `absolute`) the line is not shown.

Here is the [test site](http://writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com/#/log-in)

**HTML** - main index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" data-ng-app="wtApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <meta name="fragment" content="!">
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="yVui_k1sbN4TDHx-yDmol0MzU1QXaTTGlhNa_gVLzUs" />
        <title>Writer's Tryst, where authors and publishers, producers, agents meet.</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A better way for writers to find publishers, producers and agents" />
<!--        <base href="/" /> -->
        <link  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" data-integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" data-crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" data-integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" data-crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/shares.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/writers-tryst.png" />
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="mainController">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Writers-Tryst">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/writers-tryst-logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
                        <div id="shares">   
                            <!-- Twitter -->
                            <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com&text=<TEXT>&via=<VIA>" target="_blank" title="twitter" class="share-btn twitter">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                            </a>

                            <!-- Google Plus -->
                            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com" target="_blank" title="google+" class="share-btn google-plus">
                                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                            </a>

                            <!-- Facebook -->
                            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://writers.tryst.com" target="_blank" title="facebook" class="share-btn facebook">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                            </a>

                            <!-- StumbleUpon (url, title) -->
                            <a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn stumbleupon">
                                <i class="fa fa-stumbleupon"></i>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Reddit (url, title) -->
                            <a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn reddit">
                                <i class="fa fa-reddit"></i>
                            </a>
                            <!-- LinkedIn -->
                            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>&summary=<SUMMARY>&source=<SOURCE_URL>" target="_blank" title="linked-in" class="share-btn linkedin">
                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--navbar-header-->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Writers-Tryst">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a id="homepage" href="/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#writers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"> Writers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#enablers" id="enablers-link" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Enablers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#about" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> About</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#privacy" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> Privacy/Rules</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#contact" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> Contact</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a id="login" href="#log-in"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Log-In</a></li> 
                            <li><a id="create-account-link" href="#accounts"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Create Account</a></li> 
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" id="drop-toggle-1" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-aria-haspopup="true" data-aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a id="#update-profile" href="update-profile">Update profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="#manage-uploads" href="manage-uploads">Manage uploads</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li ><a id="#reset-pwd-link" href="reset-pwd"></a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!--navbar-collapse-->
                </div> <!--container fluid-->
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div>
            <div id="message" class="alert m-t-10"></div> 
            <div id="main" class="content">
                <!-- angular templating -->
                <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
                <div data-ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div id="foot" class="text-right small">&#169; 2016 Ronald Tornambe, Inc.</div>
         </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pages.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#drop-toggle-1").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap `panel` has a border and box-shadow.

Override it like..

```
.panel {
    border-width:0;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/CMWIpp8FAE

Answer (score 1):

it comes from this rule in bootstrap,CSS:

```css
.panel-default {
   border-color: #ddd;
}
```

so just reset this rule in your custom CSS like this:

```css
.panel-default {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about the border line just below your login section then it is because of the class panel which apply

border: 1px solid transparent;

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
```

on the Div

Answer (score 1):

Class: 'panel' adds `border: 1px solid transparent;` and class: 'panel-default' add `border-color: #ddd;` so your footer does get a border.

You can fix it by adding this to your css:

```
.panel {border:none;}
```